# Number of different values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 811777 rows and I want to find out how many different workers are involved in this dataframe. There is a column named "PERS_NR" that defines the different workers by their number but each worker is listed several times in the dataframe. I want R to tell me how many different workers are listed in the dataframe. Which code can I use? Thank U!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(PERS_NR)
```

You get the name of Pers_NR and how many times it occurs

If you only want the number of how many different workers you can use

```
library(dplyr)
n_distinct(df$PERS_NR)
```

Comment: No problem :). You can also have a look to this website

Comment: https://statisticsglobe.com/r-functions-list/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This website is really useful!